# how to get analytics for iOS video embeds (og:video)

Tags: ios, iphone, video, mobile, imessage

How can I track requests & plays for an mp4 video that is viewed/shared on imessage on ios10?

The video is embedded via `og:video` tags (and plays perfectly!) but since the user doesn't have to go to the actual site (e.g. [http://wakey.io/25](http://wakey.io/25%20WakeyWakey%20Ep%2025%20~%20Demoscene) ), I can't fire Google Analytics / MixPanel events to track those plays.

**It's great that people can now watch videos within imessage, but without any metrics, I don't know if they are watching it**.

So, what are my options here?

Answer (score -3):

A web log analyzer that uses web servers logs is your best option.

Google Analytics doesn't work because javascript it requires is never loaded.